# How to find if this function is periodic

Tags: functions, periodic-functions, fractional-part

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R, f(x) =\{\frac{x+1}{3}\}$, where { } is the fractional part.

So pretty much I have to find if this function is periodic. My first thought was this: We have ax + b so f is periodic with period $\frac{T}{a}$ (1)

We also know that {a}={a+k} so this means $\frac{x+1}{3}=\frac{x+1}{3}+T => T = 1 $ (2)

(1)+(2) => The function is periodic with period 3

But I'm not sure if this is true so I thought to ask you people. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is periodic with period $T$ then $f((x+kT)/k)=f(x/k+T)=f(x)$, so $f(x/k)$ is periodic with period $kT$ (and vice versa). Since $\{\ \}$ has perion $1$ and $k=3$ yours does have period $3$.

Comment: So it was an ok 'proof' after all. Thanks